# searchig in kibana Discover by KQL syntax

Tags: laravel, kibana, middleware

I have created a middleware in laravel! like below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\Types\String_;

class SystemActivityLogger
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return Response|RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        Log::channel('rabbitmq_elk')->info($this->prepareLogData($request));
        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare log data and log it
     * @param Request $request
     * @return string
     */
    private function prepareLogData(Request $request)
    {
      return json_encode([
          'ip' => $request->ip(),
          'url' => $request->url(),
          'agent' => $request->userAgent(),
          'date' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
          'params' => $request->query(),
       ]);
    }
}
```

this middleware is for logging and I want that `prepareLogData()` returned json type and i can search it in kibana discover with KQL syntax
this is my `sdamiii.conf` file

```
input {
       rabbitmq {
        host => "localhost"
        port => 5672
        heartbeat => 30
        queue => "system_logs"
        durable => "true"
        user => "guest"
        password => "guest"
        vhost => "/"
    }   
}
output {
       elasticsearch {
           hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
           index => "my-index-000001"
           data_stream => "false"
       }
}
```

After running ‍‍`bin/logstash -f conf.d/sdamiii.conf` command and requesting Laravel, I get this output in Kiabana.

[image]

but I do not search by KQL syntax for example i want search `message.ip` I do not receive
any results
How can I solve this problem???

Comment: The `kql` tag is for Kusto Query Language

Answer (score 0):

What result do you get when you change your prepareLogData method like this?

```
/**
 * Prepare log data and log it
 * @param Request $request
 * @return string
 */
private function prepareLogData(Request $request)
{
  return [
      'ip' => $request->ip(),
      'url' => $request->url(),
      'agent' => $request->userAgent(),
      'date' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
      'params' => $request->query(),
   ];
}
```

Comment: I get this result`"message":"array (\n 'ip' => '127.0.0.1',\n 'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/index',\n 'agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0..."`, even I have tried the filtering method in `sdamiii.conf`, but I still don't get the desired result.

Comment: you can try this? : `json_encode(your-array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);` src: https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Comment: I tested it but dont work for me:/

Comment: I think I can achieve the desired result by changing the messages in ‍`sdamiii.conf`, but I don't know how to do it.@Semih SAHIN

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire pipeline to behave `in 8.x EXACTLY` as it does with 7.13, your best path forward is to set `pipeline.ecs_compaitibility` for the pipeline.

Since you are using a configuration that gives you exactly one pipeline per Logstash process, doing so in the `logstash.yml` is reasonable. If you were running multiple pipelines, then doing so for each applicable pipeline in its `pipelines.yml` entry would be best.

If, for some reason, you want to avoid the easy path above (hint: you probably don't), it is possible to resolve this deprecation warning by adjusting your pipeline definition so that each and every plugin definition has an `ecs_compatibility => disabled` directive. This entails defining your codecs in block form, so

```
codec =>
 json becomes codec =>
   json { 
     ecs_compatibility => disabled 
   }
```

I encourage you to take the easy path, to lock in the behavior you want for the entire pipeline.
then put this fillter in `sdamiii.conf`

```
filter{
        json{
                source => "data"
        }
        json{
                source => "data.params"
        }
}

filter{
        json{
                source => "message"
        }
}
```

this is output
[image]

right now you can search with KQL language